# Client Private Key is set as part of client certificate authentication

Tags: authentication, ssl, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

I'm looking at [this example](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/openssl-create-client-server-certificate/), and I can see that as part of client authentication the user should pass the --key holding the private key used for certificate signing request to the curl command, I'm not sure why this is needed if it's for encryption shouldn't the public key of the server to be used?

Comment: It's not used for encryption, it's used for signing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the certificate itself doesn't prove anything. Certificate is never secret, can be shared freely and as such multiple parties could be in a possession of a valid client certificate.
As part of the TLS handshake with mutual authentication, client sends `CertificateVerify` message to prove it also has the private key matching the certificate it sent in `Certificate` message before. With TLS server already having client's certificate (and thus its public key), it can verify the signature.